# Why not polynomial-space reductions for $PSPACE$-hardness?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, space-complexity

A language $L'$ is $PSPACE$-hard if for every $L \in PSPACE$ we have $L \le_p L'$.

Here $L \le_p L'$ means that $L$ is polynomial-*time* reducible to $L'$.

Why does we use time reductions instead of space reductions in this situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's never interesting to use reductions that are as powerful as the complexity class you're talking about.  With the exception of $\emptyset$ and $\Sigma^*$, every problem in $\mathbf{PSPACE}$ is $\mathbf{PSPACE}$-complete under poly-space reductions.

To see this, let $X\in \mathbf{PSPACE}\setminus\{\emptyset,\Sigma^*\}$, and choose any fixed pair of strings strings $y\in X$ and $n\notin X$. Now, for any language $L\in\mathbf{PSPACE}$, we can reduce $L$ to $X$ using the function
$$f(w)=\begin{cases}\ y&\text{if }w\in L\\
                    \ n&\text{if }w\notin L.\end{cases}$$
Since $L\in\mathbf{PSPACE}$, we can compute $f$ in polynomial space.

This argument applies for any reasonable complexity class and it's the reason why, for example, we don't talk about problems being $\mathbf{P}$-complete under poly-time reductions: instead, we use something like log-space reductions, there.

In general, hardness or completeness results are "more impressive" using weaker reductions, since the reduction is able to do less of the work. In the case of $\mathbf{PSPACE}$-completeness under poly-space reductions, the reduction is actually doing *all* the work.

Comment: I see. This brings up two new questions for me then: 1) It might be reasonable to use something like log-space reductions then? 2) The reason we don't use poly-space reductions for $NPSPACE$ is because of Savitch's theorem (along with the argument used in your answer)?

Comment: @theQman Yes, logspace reductions would make sense for **PSPACE**; they're often used for **NP**, too. In practice, we tend not to use reductions more powerful than poly-time for any complexity class: the extra power doesn't seem  to buy you very much and it's easier to compare things if we're more consistent about what kind of reductions we use. You're right about **NPSPACE** and Savitch.